# Windows 8-7 downgrade, reinstallation and gpt partitions

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-activation, oem

I recently purchased 2 Acer Travelmate B113 11" laptops for use by our SMT guys when going abroad but have run into some problems. They came with Windows 8 pro downgraded to Windows 7, preinstalled with Windows 7. There is no Windows licence key sticker on the laptop, just a windows 8 sticker with no key (to be expected).

When trying to install our encryption software (Safeguard Easy 6.0) it said that it did not support GUID Partiton tables. It seems that this is not possible even with Safeguard Enterprise, only with a Bitlocker integration. This is not really an option for us.

So I wanted to reinstall windows 7 with a partiton table of my choice. Because it is an Acer, I've got no installation media and the recovery media I created using their utility just reinstalls formating the disk to GPT.

From research I've done, windows 8 pro gives you downgrade rights to windows 7 so I should be able to reinstall. Checking the key that Windows 7 is installed with says it's an OEM SLP code. This seems to be a generic code that OEM manufactures can use that does not require activiation.

After lengthy comunication with Acer, they will not supply a plain windows 7 OEM install disk.

I've tried installing windows 7 using the key I extracted but this fails to activate.
I have also tried using an activation backup tool but this does not work for OEM's unless you have the SLIC (not sure what this is).

Does anyone understand what to do in this situation with the windows licencing and is there any way round this appart from purchasing a Volume Licence key for Windows 7?

Comment: What part of the process of using the license code to install Windows 7 fails? Does the installer reject the key or are you unable to activate it?  Its entirely possible to covert GPT to MBR the problem is does your hardware support legacy mode.

Comment: It's the activation itself. It will not activate as it says it's not eligable for activation.
As for the GPT convert to MBR, please tell me how to do that as everything I've read says that you have to delete all partitons and reformat.

Comment: And my hardware does support legacy mode as it is already set, it's just the hard disk is formatted to GPT.

Comment: GPT and legacy are conflicting things. GPT indicates EFI is being used. When I converted my MBR disk to GPT I restored it from an imag by botting into a recovery image while in U/EFI mode, which then restored the image as GPT partitions. DIdn't lose a single file. **Your OEM is required by Microsoft to provide you the COA for WIndows 7** [Proof](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/how-to-activate-windows-7-using-slp-key-downloaded/182be5b1-5c47-46b7-a3ae-cf2df65c929b) the license your finding isn't your actual COA license key.  **You need that.**

Comment: It's the other way round I want but I'm trying this approach using clonzilla/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question for others that may experience the same thing.

It appears that if you have a Windows 8-7 downgrade installed on your PC, and there is no licence key sticker on the PC in question, there is no way to install a version of Windows 7 without using the recovery CD/DVD.

It's down to the Windows 7 licencing and how Windows 8 reads it's key from the BIOS.

Acer use their generic Windows 7 key which is not available to use to install the OS but is used by their OEM recovery CD.
If you installed Windows 8 on this machine it would work fine as it could read the key from the BIOS.

According to Microsoft licencing it turns out that if you have a PC purchased with a Windows 8 downgrade to Windows 7 licence, in order to an install without using the recovery methods, you would have to purchase a Volume licence key for Windows 7.

This is also related to an issue I had installing Windows 7 OEM on a PC that had Linux installed as the host OS, then Windows 7 installed as the guest in VMware. If you do this, the OEM licence apparantly is not right and you have to purchase a Volume Licence.

Just be aware of the licenceing ramifications if you want to try this.

I solved the encrypting issue by purchasing Symantec Encryption Desktop which installs okay on a GPT partition table.
In order to get it to work though, you must enable UEFI bios mode, switch off secure boot and then change back to Legacy BIOS mode.

GPT partiton does not necesarily mean UEFI. YOu can have legacy bios mode with a GPT partiton with Windows 7.